# Exiting `reverse-i-search`

Tags: bash

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to enter into `reverse-i-search` mode. I stared typing and I couldn't find the command I was looking for. Now I want to exit this search mode. If I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the last line I viewed will remain on the prompt. I don't want that. I want to go back to a completely clean prompt. How do I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy one **ctrl+c**

Comment: Ctrl+C also stops other program that may be running in the foreground. E.g. interactive shell in MC server. If you enter reverse-i-search there and use Ctrl+C, it will stop the server (which is something you don't want to do).